# Capture image from camera Fragment lost, navigate to previous Fragment

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

As I click the image from the camera, on click tick mark I automatically navigated on the previous fragment. This only happens in Redmi 6A.

**Camera intent code**-

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

**Activity Result Code**-

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();                     
                    String file_name = File_Path.getPath(getContext(), selectedImage);
                    destination = new File(file_name);
Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()))
                            .load(file_name)
                            .into(imageView);
                }
```

and **get this error-**

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.sf.lcd_density"
E/InputTransport: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: please post your code with full error log

Comment: Can you give us more detail about error

Comment: I have updated my code please check it

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: yes just save the thumbnail when you get Image from source @NavneetKrishna